# MySQL two way relationship

Tags: mysql, triggers, foreign-key-relationship

Ok so here is the problem I'm facing I'm open to complete redesigns of the schema but I think I'm basically on the right track.

**Table1 - Instructors**

```
- ID - (Auto increment int)
 - Name
 - employee ID
 - ADDITIONAL COLUMNS NOT IMPORTANT TO THIS QUESTION
 - account_id --> FK relation to (Accounts)
```

**Table2 - Students**

```
- ID - (Auto increment int)
 - Name
 - student ID
 - ADDITIONAL COLUMNS NOT IMPORTANT TO THIS QUESTION
 - account_id --> FK relation to (Accounts)
```

**Table3 - Accounts**

```
- ID - (Auto increment int)
 - USERNAME
 - PASSWORD
 - TYPE (Instructor OR Student)
 - person_id --> FK relation to (Students(ID)) & (Instructors(ID))
```

So how my logic currently flows is like this

1. INSERT a person (Student or Instructor)
2. TRIGGER INSERTS a account based on their name
3. TRIGGER UPDATES the student or instructor record with the account_id

The problem occurs because mysql doesn't allow recursive triggers because this could be very bad AKA insert into table1 then trigger on table2 inserts into table1.

But I don't see why it has a problem with me updating table one via a trigger because there is no trigger waiting to do something when it receives an update.

The reason I want the system to function like this is because there will be one central login for both instructors and students and well i know i could just do two mysql calls one to each table I would like to be able to just do one to the accounts table.

The reason I need the relationship from the person tables (Instructors/Students) to the account table is so when i delete the instructor or student the account that goes with it is deleted as well.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The question needs a little more detail. Show us the trigger statements and the errors that you are getting.